# Document.ready in included jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp, document-ready

I have a jsp jsp1 and another jsp i.e. jsp2 is included inside jsp1. There is a document.ready function in jsp2 already. When I am writing a new document.ready function in jsp1, it's not getting invoked at all. Any idea what's going wrong ? Any work around ?
For some reason, I can't modify jsp2 at all.

Comment: i was looking for the same answer. Been 9 months and no one has answered. Seems like it is not possible. Yet i hear nothing is impossible ;) .

Comment: @JunaidShirwani  Finally I came up with an idea like I have added both document.ready and window onLoad function for the same JSP. Seems like it workjed, not sure it's a good or bad approach but it worked for my scenario. Please let me know if there is any better approach to this.